# Accidentally unbound keyboard character in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard

I accidentally unbound my space key in emacs with global-unset-key SPC, sopressing SPC causes the error "SPC is undefined".  I simply want to make my space bar work again, and can't figure out how to bind a printing character to a key.  Thanks for the help.

> > Answered my own question - M-x global-set-key, SPC, self-insert-command.

Comment: Since you've answered your own question correctly, put it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution would be to start a second instance of Emacs, check what the key in question is bound to with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd><key></kbd> (i.e. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-key`), and then apply that binding back in the original instance.